# Unable to see client on Uchiwa dashboard (Sensu Monitoring)

Tags: monitoring, sensu

I have a Sensu SERVER setup and a Sensu CLIENT. 
Services sensu-server, sensu-client, uchiwa, sensu-api are running on SERVER.
Services sensu-client is running on CLIENT.

All the checks I described in `/etc/sensu/conf.d` in SERVER are listed in uchiwa.

Unfortunately, I can't see any client listed. Including the sensu-client running on SERVER.

in SERVER:

```
$ cat client.json 
{
   "client": {
      "name": "server",
      "address": "10.41.10.1",
      "subscriptions": ["ALL" ]
   }
}
```

in CLIENT:

```
$cat client.json 
{
   "client": {
      "name": "compute1",
      "address": "10.41.10.10",
      "subscriptions": [ "system","cmpt" ]
   }
}
```

How to debug this issue? I can't see any errors. I don't know if the problem is with uchiwa or sensu? Has anyone resolved a similar issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue. RabbitMQ credentials in `/etc/sensu/conf.d/rabbitmq.json` were not correct. I created a new user by going to SERVER:4567 (RabbitMQ GUI) and added those credentials in the json file.

Comment: can you please shared few more details. i'm also having some issue with adding client

Comment: @roshan Could you please describe the issue?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually i'm not sure whether its a problem with Uchiwa or my setup configeration of Sensu client. Can you please provide some links to setup sensu client on Amazon linux AMI